# Moq callback not modifying input parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ado.net, moq

**The problem:**

The code below does not allow me to modify the parameters that I pass into a method that has been mocked with Moq.

**Additional details:**

I am attempting to mock a generic data access object that provides a method called `ExecuteStoredProcedureWithParameters`.  The method accepts two parameters: a stored procedure name and a collection of `SqlParameter` objects.  I have stored procedures that return values via output parameters, so I am attempting to mock the data access method and modify the value of the output parameter (which is a member of the `SqlParameter` collection that gets passed in).  From my research, the code I have below seems like it should work (I'm just attempting to modify the input parameters by setting them to empty/null for testing purposes).  The return value I specified in my mock setup gets returned and stored in `retval`, however the values of `testProcedure` and `testParameters` remain unchanged after the mock method is executed.  What am I doing wrong and how can I modify the objects that are passed into my mock method?

**My interface:**

```
public interface IGenericDAO
{
    int ExecuteStoredProcedureWithParameters(string procedureName, Collection<SqlParameter> parameters);
}
```

**Test method:**

```
// Create a mock generic DAO
var mock = new Mock<IGenericDAO>();
mock.Setup(x => x.ExecuteStoredProcedureWithParameters("TestProcedure", It.IsAny<Collection<SqlParameter>>()))
    .Returns(111)
    .Callback<string, Collection<SqlParameter>>((proc, prms) => { proc = string.Empty; prms = null; });

// Execute the mocked method with dummy parameters
var testProcedure = "TestProcedure";
var testParameters = new Collection<SqlParameter>();
var retval = mock.Object.ExecuteStoredProcedureWithParameters(testProcedure, testParameters);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the local variable `prms` to null. This has no effect on the actual `testParameters` variable because of standard ***pass-by-value*** semantics. The `Collection` is passed by value into the function and so is shallow-copied like any other variable. What you are doing is similar to this trivial example:

```
void A()
{
    int x = 10;
    B(x);
    Console.WriteLine(x); // 'x' is still 10
}

void B(int x) // input argument copied into local 'x'
{
    x = 20;   // local 'x' modified
}             // local 'x' discarded
```

This will print out 10, because only the local copy `x` is modified and then thrown away at the end of the function.

In your actual example, if do something like `prms.Add(new SqlParameter(...))` then, at the end of the call, `testParameters` will contain the added value.